# How to use Azure Search Service with heterogenous data sources

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have worked on *Azure Search service* previously where I created an indexer directly on a SQL DB in the Azure Portal.

Now I have a use-case where I would want to ingest from multiple data sources each having different data schema. Assume these data sources to be 3 search APIs of X,Y,Z teams. All of them take search term and gives back results in their own schema. I want my Azure Search Service to be proxy for these so that I have one search API that a user can use to get results from multiple sources, **ordered correctly**.

How should I go about doing it? I assume that I might have to create a common schema and whenever user searches something, I would call these 3 APIs and get results, map them to a common schema and then index this data in common schema into Azure Search index. Finally, call this Azure Search API to give back the results to the caller.

I would appreciate any help! If I can get  hold of a better documentation for doing this work, that will be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. You can work with 3 different indexes and fire queries against them, or you can try to combine all of them in the same index. The benefit of the second approach is a better way to implement ordering / paging as all the information will be stored in the same index.

Comment: How should I go about exactly implementing unified solution? I would appreciate if there is a good documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by *ordered correctly*. Should team X be able to see results from teams Y and Z? The only way you can get ranked results like this is to maintain a single index with a common schema containing data from all teams.

One potential pitfall with this approach is conflicts in the schema. For example if one team requires a field to be of a specific datatype or use a specific analyzer, while another team has different requirements. We do this in our indexes, but with some carefully selected common fields and then dedicated fields prefixed according to our own naming convention to avoid conflicts.

One thing to consider is the need to reset the index. If you need to add, change or remove fields you will have to delete the index and create it again with a new schema. If you have a common index and team X needs to add a new property, you would need to reset (delete and create) the common index which affects all teams.

So, creating separate indexes per team has its benefits. Each team can have their own schema without risk of conflicts and they can reset their index without affecting the other teams.

Comment: There is just one team, i.e. one type of user. I think you misunderstood a little. What I am saying is I have a problem where I would want to assimilate results from more than one data source. In order to do that, I would want just one search index. This search index should be on the results from these data sources so that search results I get is ordered/ranked correctly to the end-user. Problem is these data sources I am talking about are search API themselves. I don't have more than one type of user and I don't want data to be restricted for some and accessible to others.

Comment: What I have found from my research is there is no better way of doing it. MS Search is working on a solution though that I could use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview
I think this might be the solution I was looking for.